# Find all real solutions for the system: $ x+y-z=-1$, $x^2-y^2+z^2=1,$ $-x^3+y^3+z^3=-1.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, systems-of-equations

> Find all real solutions for the following system:
>   $$
> \left\{ 
> \begin{array}{l}
> x+y-z=-1 \\ 
> x^2-y^2+z^2=1\\ 
> -x^3+y^3+z^3=-1
> \end{array}
> \right. 
> $$

From a math olympiad (IberoAmericana, 1992). This was taken from a book, with no answer provided.

My usual tricks using symmetric polynomials appear not to work here (or I'm don't know how to apply them). A possible solution (by inspection) is $(x,y,z)=(-1,-1,-1)$, but there might be others.

Hints and full answers demonstrating all possible solutions are appreciated.

Comment: See my answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2497260/equation-system-with-3-variables/2497313#2497313

Comment: For sure a duplicate... thanks for pointing out the available solution.

Comment: A hint: $$x^2 - y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$$

And in the first one you know what $(x+y)$ is, in terms of $z$, et cetera. Come on kid, put yourself into the game.